# Uniform convergence NBHM(2019)

Tags: uniform-convergence

> Check the uniform convergence of following :
>
> 1)  $f_{n}(x)=n\log(1+ \frac{x^{2}}{n})$ on $\mathbb{R}$
>
> 2) The series $\sum_{1}^{\infty}2^{n}$$\sin(\frac{1}{3^{n}x})$ on $[1,\infty)$

For the first question, I applied the $M_n$ test for uniform convergence but not getting the ideal value of $x$ .I am getting $x=0$,but it does't work here.

In second question, I don't have any idea which test should I use

Please help and  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

- $n \log\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n}\right)=\log\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n}\right)^n \to \log e^{x^2}=x^2$
- $2^{n}\sin\left(\frac{1}{3^{n}x}\right)= \frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n \left[\frac{\sin \left(\frac{1}{3^nx}\right)}{\frac{1}{3^nx}}\right]$ and note that $\frac{2}{3}<1$ and $\frac{1}{x}<1$

Comment: and $x^{2}$ is not uniform convergent over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: in second for x in $[1,\infty)$ it will always less then$ \frac{2}{3}$ so it is also uniformaly covergence ,,thnx for your answer

Comment: Yes! In the second, first and third quantities are bounded by 1 and 2 respectively, , so $$\left|2^n \sin \left(\frac{1}{3^nx}\right)\right| \leq 2 \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$$ and $\sum \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$ converges, so by $M_n$ test, result follows!